# Out of Universe, how many TARDIS props have been used?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, props

**Out of Universe:**

I was having a chat conversation recently regarding the TARDIS from the *Doctor Who* television series.  I became curious as to how many TARDIS props were created for the television show beginning with the first episode that aired in 1963.  I know that Doctor Who has a huge fan base.  I was curious if any of the TARDIS props used were owned by private collectors or if there are on display somewhere.

I admittedly do not know much about this show.  I have only seen about 3-4 episodes of the "new" *Doctor Who*.  I tried doing research on the subject, but I am completely unaware as to which sources are credible and which are not.

My question is:

**How many total TARDIS props were made for the television series beginning with the first episode in 1963 to present?  If there are any props that are not being used in the show anymore, where are they located?**

**Note**:  I am only asking about the police box.  Exterior only:

[image: TARDIS]

Comment: Some good info here; http://www.themindrobber.co.uk/tardis-police-box-mobile.php

Comment: There are currently [several TARDISes dotted around Glasgow](https://peoplemakeglasgow.com/things-to-do/visitor-itineraries/the-whovian-guide-to-glasgow) ([one sells hot dogs!](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-hot-dog-stall-in-old-police-box-glasgow-135065698.html)), although I presume they’re not actual production props from the show.

Comment: The gaming society at teh college I work for have built their own Tardis, and a Dalek.  Dalek is neat - it has motors, a person (5'11" tall) can get in it and control it, etc.  I've loaned them my scarf for photo ops...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite We have one in London that's also very fake, outside Earls Court Station.

Comment: I believe a bare minimum of 4; I remember in reading the *ABOUT TIME* books that they had at least two props during the original run. I find it hard to believe that that would have shipped the existing prop (even if they still had it) to the US for the Movie (8th Doctor); and, I'm 99+% certain the current prop is actually bigger on the outside than the original.

Comment: This article counts 10 distinct props in the revival run alone, between 2005 and 2017: https://medium.com/tardis-history/the-props-74481fcd14c4

Comment: @PaulD.Waite those are actual old Police Boxes. What the TARDIS is (usually) disguised as.

Comment: @OrangeDog that’s exactly what the TARDISes want you to think.

Answer (score 12):

As of 2020, there have been **nineteen** known full size TARDIS Police Box exterior props.

1. Original 1963 prop. Lamp was replaced in season two. Various refurbishments were made over the years, including a new roof, new signs, doors, the addition of handles, and a repaint.
2. Incomplete prop from *The Massacre*. A "fake" TARDIS was constructed for location shooting, only having two walls.
3. Prop for the Peter Cushing films. Apparently they both used the same one.
4. In 1976 an entire new prop was constructed after the continued deterioration of the original. This had a couple of changes to the roof over time.
5. In 1980 a fibreglass prop was built. This was repainted in 1983.
6. Another fibreglass copy was made in 1986.
7. Prop was built for the Paul McGann film.

8-11. New wooden props built for the 2005 revival

12. A fibreglass copy of the 2005 prop.
13. New prop for Matt Smith's TARDIS.
14. Another one built in 2011. This was repainted a few times and signage changed.
15. Another in 2013. Again eventually repainted and re-signed.
16. Another prop built in 2015.

17-18. Two identical props built in 2017 for Jodie Whittaker's new TARDIS design.

19. Another one built in 2018.

I *think* a new one was used for the Flux series in 2021, but I haven't seen any confirmation.

---

Sources:

- [themindrobber.co.uk](http://www.themindrobber.co.uk/tardis-police-box-mobile.php)
- [Will Brooks](https://medium.com/tardis-history/the-props-74481fcd14c4)

Comment: https://www.thepropgallery.com/in-detail-tardis-filming-miniature - Ahem

Comment: The episode Flatline features at least four miniature TARDIS's; https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Flatline_(TV_story)

Comment: @Valorum that's why I said "full size"